# App not running on tvOS 10 Beta

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I put the tvOS 10 beta on my Apple TV to test my app. It works fine on tvOS 9.2 but after I opened it in Xcode 8 beta and updated the swift syntax to Swift 3, the app will "run" but it just shows a blank screen, giving me no errors or feedback.

I am guessing it is something to do with my Java Script and TVML files in my server that my app connects to, but not sure what I would need to do to update it.

Anyone else having this issue or know a possible fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tvOS Simulator is very very slow for us (i.e. not working in beta 1). Launch the tvOS Simulator stand alone to test if the Sim is actually working for you..

Comment: My simulator just sits there on the loading screen.